# Cardinality of algebraic extensions of an infinite field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, cardinals

An exercise in Lang's algebra book is: let $k$ an infinite field, and $E$ an algebraic extension of $k$. Then $E$ has the same cardinality as $k$. How can one can prove this?

Comment: Might I inquire as to why you unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 16):

**HINT:** First prove that $k[x]$ and $k$ have the same cardinality, you can do that by showing that $k[x]\cong\bigcup k^n$, and by induction $k^n$ and $k$ have the same cardinality, so $|k[x]|=\aleph_0\cdot|k|=|k|$; then show there is a surjection from $k[x]$ onto $E$, and an injection from $k$ into $E$. Conclude the wanted equality.

(Note that this makes a heavy use of the axiom of choice, and indeed without the axiom of choice one *might* have a counterexample of an algebraic closure of the rational numbers which is not countable.)

Comment: Classic and clean!  I know it's possible for the closure not to exist or for multiple nonisomorphic versions to exist, but is it known for sure that the algebraic closure of the rationals _can_ be larger without choice?

Comment: Steven, the most famous result is due to Lauchli's, where he shows the consistency of an uncountable closure of the rational.

Comment: To read more about the choice connection, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114978/algebraic-closure-for-mathbbq-or-mathbbf-p-without-choice should be just fine.

Comment: The axiom of choice (by means of the lemma of zorn) is invoked in showing $|k\times k|=|k|$, right? and the existence of the surjection and the injection is just due to the fact that $E$ is algebraic and $E\supset k$, respectively? We also use the Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem, isn't it? sorry I am not so versed in these things

Comment: @000: The axiom of choice is indeed used to show that $k[x]$ and $k$ have the same cardinality, as well to show that injection+surjection implies a bijection.

Comment: How you defining map from K[x] to E (to show surjection)? Since polynomial in K[X] can have more than one root, How can I ensure the map is well-defined?

Comment: @infintedimensional the roots of $p$ are exactly the roots of $p^n$ for all $n>1$.

Answer (score 10):

There is a **canonical** map $\operatorname {minpol}:E\to k[X]$ sending an element $e\in E$ to its minimal polynomial $\operatorname {minpol}_e(X)\in k[X]$ over $k$.
Since the image $\operatorname {minpol}(E)\subset k[X]$ contains all the affine polynomials $X-q \;(q\in k)$, that image $\operatorname {minpol}(E)$ has the same cardinality as $k$ (since $k$ and $k[X]$ have same cardinality, as already  remarked by Asaf).
Since the fibers of $\operatorname {minpol}: E\to \operatorname {minpol}(E)$ are finite and non empty, the set $E$ also has the cardinality of $k$, as desired.

Comment: Yeah, but there's nothing wrong with that. :-)

Comment: Dear 000, thanks for the kind words, but don't worry about acceptance: I'm happy just knowing that my answer was of some help to you.

Comment: Some bravely anonymous users have downvoted this answer. I don't care a fig but want to reassure readers that the answer is perfectly correct and completete: if anybody thinks otherwise, let him comment here. But I'm not holding my breath...